# Why do I get an "ErrorID: 512 invalid clientID" even though the ID is correct?

Tags: php, teamspeak, ts3phpframework

I've got a php TeamSpeak Bot for quite a while and for one user I now have this weird phenomenon, that the clientID is invalid.

So I store the clientIDs (TeamSpeakUUID) in a MySQL database.

As example:

I fetch the TeamSpeakUUID from the database and want to poke a client on my TeamSpeak with the TS3 PHP Framework (https://github.com/planetteamspeak/ts3phpframework).
For every other client it works expect for one and I have absolutely no idea why.

snippet for the example:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $client = $ts3_VirtualServer->clientGetByUid($row['TeamSpeakUUID'], true);
  $client->poke($msg);
}
```

I have two UUIDs here

> Working: sP0GjP/pVyyfx07MvN+S1Cvt9mc=
>
> Not working: a/1nYOo3Ej3afLa05ElVtxYDOMU=

I don't know why but if I want to poke the client "hardcoded" it works...

```
$client = $ts3_VirtualServer->clientGetByUid("a/1nYOo3Ej3afLa05ElVtxYDOMU=", true);
```

Do you guys have any idea(s)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)